# COMMAND + CLICK not working in feature file to send to step definitions

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, cucumber

I have a project based on cucumber JAVA language and need the function that sends from feature file to step definitions, but it is not working!

I use eclipse photon 4.8 (I also tried the different version like 4.7.2, 4.9, 4.1.0) and I use plugin Natural 0.7.6 and function COMMAND + CLICK or F3 not working at all! But the same project works fine with that command on friend laptop! So I think it is some eclipse settings, who knows how to fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to check and fix settings for shortcuts, but it did not help. Then I tried to uninstalled unused plugins ( Gradel) and then update Eclipse from version photon 4.8 to version 2019-09 R (4.13.0) and that helped. Now shortcuts in cucumber feature file working.